# Como eu crio um ArrayList de objetos com cada posição contendo um novo objeto?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Produto {

       String marca;
       int quant;

       Produto prod = new Produto();
       ArrayList <Produto> lista_de_produtos = new ArrayList<>(); 
       lista_de_produtos.add(new Produto());

       //É dessa forma?

}
```

Comment: Está tendo algum problema? É isto que faz o que perguntou. Claro, tem um monte de problemas em fazer de forma tão simples, mas aí depende do contexto.

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Dê um exemplo do que quer alcançar.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Não deve fazer assim. O código compila e executa, mas esta forma é considerada errada.

A classe chama `Produto`, então o que espera ter dentro dela? Um produto, certo? Por que encontra uma lista de produtos nesse objeto? Pior ainda, haverá uma lista diferente em cada produto. Isto não faz o menor sentido. Se pelo menos a lista fosse estática, e aí pertencente à classe e não ao objeto, até teria um sentido parcial, mas ainda estaria errado conceitualmente porque isto deveria estar em uma outra classe de controle do estoque e não ao produto.

Conceitualmente deveria ter uma outra classe que cuida da lista de produtos. Nem vou entrar no mérito da aplicação poder rodar em ambiente concorrente e isto daria problema, vou considerar isso uma possibilidade inexistente.

Outro problema desta classe é que o construtor não aceita parâmetros, ou seja, ele não [funciona como construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) de fato. Isto é outro erro conceitual. Também não falei sobre o encapsulamento e abstração, porque isso é mais confuso ainda e há controvérsias, e nem estou dizendo que deveria fazer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a sua questão e os comentários entre você e o **@Maniero**, eu irei deixar a minha resposta aqui abaixo, porém deixo claro que você deve se atentar sobre o seguinte do **@Maniero**:

- **a)** Leia com atenção a resposta do mesmo.
- **b)** Leia com atenção os comentários em sua resposta para sua própria pergunta.

Bem, vamos lá... Como você não detalhou a sua pergunta, como por exemplo: **"O que você deseja realmente?"**, **"Quais são as regras de negócios?"** entre outros, eu deixarei abaixo as explicações de conceitos e como devem ser utilizados do modo correto.

**O que é um ArrayList?**

> A Classe `ArrayList` é uma **matriz redimensionável** , que pode ser encontrada no pacote `java.util`. A diferença entre uma **matriz interna** e uma `ArrayList` em `Java` é a seguinte:
>
> - O tamanho de uma matriz não pode ser modificado (se você quiser adicionar ou remover elementos de/para uma matriz, será necessário criar uma nova).
> - Enquanto em um `ArrayList` os elementos podem ser adicionados e removidos de um sempre que quiser.
> - A sintaxe entre um `ArrayList` e uma **matriz interna** também é um pouco diferente

**Como criar um ArrayList?**

> Você deve importar a biblioteca (pacote) do mesmo e após isto instanciar o objeto, inserindo o tipo dele e o seu nome, como por exemplo:

```
// importa a biblioteca (pacote) do ArrayList
import java.util.ArrayList;

// Cria um Objeto de ArrayList chamado cars e do tipo de armazenamento String
ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>(); 

// Cria um Objeto de ArrayList chamado cars e do tipo de armazenamento Car
Car carObj = new Car();
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

**Como armazenar os dados em um ArrayList?**

```
ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    cars.add("Volvo");
    cars.add("BMW");
    cars.add("Ford");
    cars.add("Mazda");
```

**Como acessar o index de um ArrayList?**

```
cars.get(0);
cars.get(1);
cars.get(2);
```

Agora dando exemplo utilizando sua pergunta, utilizando uma situação simples e de apenas para ganhos de conhecimento, você deve fazer o seguinte:

> - Criar uma Classe para Produtos
> - Criar uma Classe para Lista de Produtos

**ListaProduto.class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListaProduto {
    private ArrayList<Produto> arrProd;
    
    public ListaProduto() {
        this.arrProd = new ArrayList<Produto>();
    }
    
    public void addProd(Produto prod) {
        this.arrProd.add(prod);
    }
    
    public void getAllProd() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.arrProd.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\nREF DO OBJ: " + this.arrProd.get(i) + " -- "  + "MARCA: " + this.arrProd.get(i).getMarca() + " -- QUANTIDADE: " + this.arrProd.get(i).getQuantidade());
        }
    }

    
}
```

**Produto.java**

```
public class Produto {
    private String marca;
    private int quantidade;
    
    public Produto(String marca, int quantidade) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }
    
    public String getMarca() {
        return this.marca;
    }
    
    public int getQuantidade() {
        return this.quantidade;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListaProduto lp = new ListaProduto();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            lp.addProd(new Produto("PRODUTO " + i, i));
        }
        
        lp.getAllProd();
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
REF DA CLASS: Produto@15db9742 -- MARCA: PRODUTO 0 -- QUANTIDADE: 0
REF DA CLASS: Produto@6d06d69c -- MARCA: PRODUTO 1 -- QUANTIDADE: 1
REF DA CLASS: Produto@7852e922 -- MARCA: PRODUTO 2 -- QUANTIDADE: 2
REF DA CLASS: Produto@4e25154f -- MARCA: PRODUTO 3 -- QUANTIDADE: 3
```

**NOTA:**

> O código acima foi dada para fins de ganhos de conhecimento, existem diversas outras formas e principalmente melhores e com boas práticas para se fazer o mesmo.

[FONTE OFICIAL - W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente é dessa forma mesmo. É importante lembrar do contexto da sua aplicação. De uma forma mais geral esse é o código que usei pra validar.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Produto {

    public Produto(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     String marca;
     int quant;

     Produto prod = new Produto();
     ArrayList<Produto> lista_de_produtos = new ArrayList<>(); 
     lista_de_produtos.add(new Produto());
     lista_de_produtos.add(new Produto());

    }

}
```

Comment: Você diz que é assim, mas escreveu um código que faz algo diferente, não entendi.

Comment: O código está criando um ArrayList e em cada posição tem um novo produto. Talvez você esteja confundindo alguns conceitos da linguagem. O que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: Eu não quero fazer nada, eu estou dizendo que sua resposta é contraditória, ela diz que o código da pergunta está correto, mas diz para fazer de outro jeito. Isso que não entendi, se o código dele está correto por que está dizendo para fazer de outro jeito? Que conceitos da linguagem você acha que eu estou confundindo?

Comment: Respondi mais acima que basicamente da forma que você fez está certa e que validei isso através do código que coloquei na resposta: Criando uma classe e executando o código que você fez em um método main. Somente isso.

Comment: Eu não fiz nada, eu só dei uma resposta, pode lê-la. Me desculpe mas tudo isso que está falando não faz sentido. Já vi que ficaremos em círculos.

Comment: @IranNeto acho que o que o @Maniero quer dizer é o seguinte: Na sua pergunta o seu código não faz o menor sentido, pois na `class Produto {}` você está instanciando e criando novos objetos dela, nela mesma e adicionando os objetos dos produtos em um `ArrayList`. O qual isto não faz o menor sentido e quebra muitos conceitos da linguagem, para se fazer isto você precisa criar uma outra classe que é uma lista de produtos e instânciar o produto e o array lá dentro.

Comment: @Maniero é isto?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS nem cheguei nesse ponto, só o fato de escrever que um código está certo e aí mostrar outro já não faz sentido, se está certo não deveria mostrar outro. Também não faz muito sentido fazer isso, embora dependendo do contexto não é um grande problema, na verdade este código da resposta está mais adequado que o da pergunta (para um exercício), e nem é por questão do conceito da linguagem, é por questão semântica do código como um todo, é um problema do domínio, na minha resposta eu falo sobre isto.

Comment: Pera ai esse código ta certo em um contexto? Desculpa mas o "SOLID" que existe dentro de min deu conflito, e me deu um bug...

Comment: @RicardoLucas sim, o de um exercício muito básico que esteja avaliando outro aspecto, o de um software throw away e muitos outros que não exigem nada muito correto pra funcionar.