# Como inicializar um ArrayList no construtor?

Tags: java, arraylist, construtor

Tenho que desenvolver um programa em Java que faça o aluguel de uma biblioteca.

Em uma parte do programa tenho que fazer um `ArrayList` de publicações, segue a questão:

> Devemos criar um sistema para controle de bibliotecas e seus empréstimos. Uma biblioteca possui um nome, um endereço e armazena um conjunto de publicações. Atualmente, as publicações disponíveis são os artigos, livros e teses. Todas as publicações possuem data de publicação, um título, uma lista de outras publicações a que elas fazem referência e o conjunto de autores da publicação. São atributos relevantes para um autor o seu nome e sua titulação. São atributos relevantes para artigos o seu título, a sua data de publicação, o seus autores, as outras
>   publicações que ele faz referência e o seu resumo. Para os livros é relevante armazenar seu título, sua data de publicação, as outras publicações que ele referencia, seus autores, o número da edição, o nome da editora e o seu ISBN. Para as teses é relevante armazenar seu título, sua data de publicação, as outras publicações que ela faz referência, o autor da tese, o número de páginas, resumo, data da defesa e a instituição na qual a tese foi defendida.

Quando crio a classe `Biblioteca`, e coloco o `ArrayList` das publicações no construtor, como funciona a implementação desse `ArrayList`? Tenho que fazer um método dentro da classe para preencher o mesmo? Segue código da classe que fiz.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Biblioteca {
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private ArrayList<Publicacoes> publicacoes;


    public Biblioteca(String nome, String endereco, ArrayList<Publicacoes> publicacoes) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.publicacoes = publicacoes;
    }


    String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }


    void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }


    String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }


    void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }


    ArrayList<Publicacoes> getPublicacoes() {
        return publicacoes;
    }


    void setPublicacoes(ArrayList<Publicacoes> publicacoes) {
        this.publicacoes = publicacoes;
    }


}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como eu crio um ArrayList de objetos com cada posição contendo um novo objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387004/como-eu-crio-um-arraylist-de-objetos-com-cada-posi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-contendo-um-novo-objeto)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas coisas esquisitas nesta classe. A primeira delas é chamar o `super()`em uma classe que não herda de nada a não ser `Object`, já dá para afirmar que isto não é necessário, afinal o construtor de `Object` faz nada.

Não faz sentido o código externo passar um *array* no construtor ou acessar isso diretamente, na verdade código externo nem deveria saber que tem um *array* aí dentro, isto é [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). A `Biblioteca` deveria permitir adicionar, remover, modificar e acessar uma publicação. Então tem que criar métodos para fazer estas operações. Acho que isto já responde a pergunta, a não ser que queira que façamos esses métodos para você, oque não é nosso objetivo.

Aí vem outro erro conceitual, esse *array* que deveria ser interno contém vários elementos do tipo `Publicacao` já que cada um é individual, não cabe plural ali.

Eu sempre questionaria o [uso de *getter* e *setter*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101). Tem casos que deve usar, mas não em todos, essa é uma das pragas que tomou os códigos porque as pessoas só copiam o que outros fazem sem entender a motivação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).