# Criando cadastro de produto usando arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Gostaria de criar um programa de cadastro de produto usando o `ArrayList`.

Como coloco um loop para ler `NOME`, `MODELO`, `TAMANHO` e `PREÇO` e armazenar esse primeiro loop em um local do array list?

O que código que  fiz está entrando cada dado em um local de array.

```
 public class CadastroProduto {

    ArrayList cadastroProduto = new ArrayList();

    private String nome;
    private String modelo;
    private String tamanho;
    private double preco;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        cadastroProduto.add(nome);
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        cadastroProduto.add(modelo);
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }

    public void setTamanho(String tamanho) {
        cadastroProduto.add(tamanho);
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
    }

    public double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(double preco) {
        cadastroProduto.add(preco);
        this.preco = preco;
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dados = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner dados1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner dados2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner dados3 = new Scanner(System.in);

        CadastroProduto c1 = new CadastroProduto();

        String nome = "";
        String modelo = "";
        String tamanho = "";
        double preco = 0;

        System.out.println("Opçoes\n 1-Cadastrar produto\n 2-Remover produto\n 3-Verificar produto\n 4-Dinheiro\n");
        int numopc = 0;
        System.out.print("nº: ");

        numopc = dados.nextInt();

        while (numopc == 1) {

            switch (numopc) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Nome do produto: ");
                    nome = dados1.nextLine();
                    c1.setNome(nome);

                    System.out.println("Modelo do produto: ");
                    modelo = dados2.nextLine();
                    c1.setModelo(modelo);

                    System.out.println("Tamanho do produto: ");
                    tamanho = dados3.nextLine();
                    c1.setTamanho(tamanho);

                    System.out.println("Preço do produto: ");
                    preco = dados.nextDouble();
                    c1.setPreco(preco);

                    System.out.println("\n Cadastrar mais produtos?\n  1-Sim\n  0-Não\n");
                    numopc = dados.nextInt();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    break;

            }


        }
        System.out.println(c1.cadastroProduto.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Tem, mas não compensa fazer para um exercício, Eu costumo fazer este tipo de coisa criando abstrações, mas quase ninguém faz, e pra quem está começando eu não recomendo, pelo menos até ter confiança para descobrir como fazer isso por conta própria porque é o tip oda coisa que exige um certo domínio, independência para realizar. No momento você está errando em coisas muito mais básicas, como criar vários *scanners* sem necessidade, organização do que é uma classe (o problema mais grave), seguir receitas de bolo que nada ajudam o código ficar melhor, criar variáveis desnecessárias, repetição...

Comment: Leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387029/101

Comment: Isto é um exercício para faculdade? teria o enunciado ai pra mostrar (já fiz alguns trabalhos assim antes na época da faculdade)?

Comment: Maniero, Scanner se eu criar uma so ele pula uma leitra de entrada de dado e nao sei pq e so da certo com varios scanner (gambiarra kk). vou olha o link que me mando, obrigado

Comment: @Elizeu, nao eh exercicio de faculdade. estou fazendo por conta. se recomendar para fazer de outra maneira que seja possivel para mim, so q sou iniciante estou no segundo 2ºsemestre da faculdade.

Comment: @Pedro segue abaixo um projeto que acabo de criar. Qualquer dúvida utilize o chat no neste link que assim que eu puder te respondo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/95753/duvida-projeto-crud-com-array-lista?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa para você fazer é dessa maneira

Pois usa um padrão de arquitetura de software conhecido como MVC (Model, View, Controler), que separa o projeto em camadas, assim deixando o código mais limpo e reutilizável.

Apesar que neste exemplo você não usa Interface, e sim o terminal, seria bom criar um CRUD com o array, ia ficar show.

Um pouco mais sobre MVC: https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-padrao-mvc/29308

Classe CadastroProduto

```
public class CadastroProduto {

    private String nome;
    private String modelo;
    private String tamanho;
    private double preco;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public String getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }

    public double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public void setTamanho(String tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
    }

    public void setPreco(double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
```

Classe Principal

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner dados = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner dados1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner dados2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner dados3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    ProdutoController produtoController = new ProdutoController();
    CadastroProduto c1 = new CadastroProduto();

    String nome = "";
    String modelo = "";
    String tamanho = "";
    double preco = 0;

    System.out.println(
            "Opçoes\n 1-Cadastrar produto\n 2-Remover produto\n 3-Verificar produto\n 4-Dinheiro\n");
    int numopc = 0;

    System.out.print(
            "nº: ");

    numopc = dados.nextInt();

    while (numopc
            == 1) {

        switch (numopc) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Nome do produto: ");
                nome = dados1.nextLine();
                c1.setNome(nome);

                System.out.println("Modelo do produto: ");
                modelo = dados2.nextLine();
                c1.setModelo(modelo);

                System.out.println("Tamanho do produto: ");
                tamanho = dados3.nextLine();
                c1.setTamanho(tamanho);

                System.out.println("Preço do produto: ");
                preco = dados.nextDouble();
                c1.setPreco(preco);

                System.out.println("\n Cadastrar mais produtos?\n  1-Sim\n  0-Não\n");
                numopc = dados.nextInt();

                produtoController.adicionar(c1);
                c1 = new CadastroProduto();
                break;

            case 2:
                break;
        }

    }

    produtoController.listaProdutos();
}
```

Classe ProdutoController

```
public class ProdutoController {

List<CadastroProduto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

public void adicionar(CadastroProduto cp) {
    produtos.add(cp);
}

public void listaProdutos() {
    produtos.forEach((p) -> {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + p.getNome());
        System.out.println("Modelo: " + p.getModelo());
        System.out.println("Tamanho: " + p.getTamanho());
        System.out.println("Preço: " + p.getPreco());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Por que é a melhor?

Comment: Editei o post, na verdade me expressei mal, é realmente só uma alternativa para a solução do problema dele, obrigado pela observação amigo.